# Table View Prototype Content Wrong Width

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to make my prototype content match the width of the table view, but I cannot get this to work. I set the leading and trailing margins of the table view to 0, but the prototype content refuses to match the width of the table view. How can I get the prototype content width to match that of the tableview?

[image: iPad Pro 9.7"]

[image: iPhone SE (content offscreen)]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of Xcode. The content have the same width of the tableView but Xcode show it wrong.